# When is it right to not have a normalized database?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, normalization

Here's the situation:

Let's say I have a Dog model and a Vaccination model (so, a table storing rows of Dogs and a table storing rows of Vaccinations that was given to a Dog).

So, a Dog `has_many` Vaccinations and a Vaccinations `belongs_to` a Dog.

I want to be able to answer quickly the question: "When was the last time Dog A got a Vaccination?" There are two ways to store this data:

1) Normalized database way: let the Vaccine table store everything. To answer the question, search the DB for all Vaccinations given to Dog A, and return the most recent one.

2) Not normalized database way: Have a field in Dog called "last_vaccination", and maintain this field every time a Vaccination is given to Dog A.

The pros of #1 are: you get database normalization and don't have to worry about maintaining accurate data.

The pros of #2 are: performance-- you don't have to search the Vaccine database every time.

What's the right way to do this???

Comment: This is obviously a very simple example, the reason for normalization is to have data specific to the primary key in each table.  I would say that you want to normalize your tables whenever possible otherwise you will end up with a table that is just absolutely enormous storing all your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a big fan of a saying I heard from a DB guy at a software symposium years ago:

"Normalize til it hurts, denormalize til it works."

Lots of truth in that.

FWIW, I think there's a hole in the layout above - a "Vaccinations" table needs to be there that, in effect, ties the Dog to the Vaccine. Vaccinations != vaccines. That's a more accurate representation of the normalized version. IMO.

Comment: Agreed. Vaccinations is a table that has many-to-many relationships to both dog and vaccines. It would have at least 4 columns: id(PK), dog_id (FK), vaccine_id (FK), vaccination_date.

Comment: @DavidW Let's assume there's only one type of Vaccination. I updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, one of the things that I've come to realize in situations like this is:

If you find the need to constantly store aggregate or 'latest record' information in another table (and breaking normalization), primarily for performance purposes, then what you really need is a cache, *not* a column/table.

Choose your poison: a simple in-memory cache, a distributed cache, or a NoSQL complement to your RDBMS.

In your particular case, The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work might go something like:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("dogs/#{@dog.id}/last_vaccination") do
  @dog.vaccinations.last
end
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that I still have to implement the business logic to update the cache every time a new record is added, right?

Comment: You could use `@dog.cache_key` instead of `@dog.id`. It includes updated_at timestamp, that ensures the cache is always fresh. Just make sure the timestamp is updated each time new vaccination is added:  `Vaccination.belongs_to :dog, touch: true`